# Pig: Aggregate with specific parameter dynamically

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have data some data that I want to plot, but the aggregation parameter is dependent on the user. The data looks like this-

```
Date Country Browser Count
---- ------- ------- -----
2015-07-11,US,Chrome,18
2015-07-11,US,Opera Mini,10
2015-07-11,US,Firefox,21
2015-07-11,US,IE,11
2015-07-11,US,Safari,8
...
2015-07-11,UK,Chrome,102
2015-07-11,UK,IE,45
2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Safari,47
2015-07-11,UK,Firefox,40
...
2015-07-11,DE,Android browser,50
2015-07-11,DE,Chrome,3
2015-07-11,DE,IE,11
2015-07-11,DE,Firefox,20
```

The user will tell me what to aggregate by (country or browser), and I want to display the counts. For example, grouped by country (aggregated by browser) it would be -

```
2015-07-11,US,ALL,68
2015-07-11,UK,ALL,234
2015-07-11,DE,ALL,84
```

whereas grouped by browser (aggregated by country) might be -

```
2015-07-11,ALL,IE,67
2015-07-11,ALL,Chrome,123
2015-07-11,ALL,Firefox,81
```

Would I have to write separate scripts based on each column or are there more efficient ways of doing this?

Comment: Would suggest to go for a macro, have added a sample script  for ref.

Answer (score 0):

Better to write a macro to which the the alias name and the field name : 'country', 'browser' is passed. Aggregation logic remains the same.

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#macros

**Example :**

**Pig script :**

```
DEFINE AGGR_DATA(alias, field_name) RETURN aggr_alias {

  alias_grp = GROUP $alias BY $field_name;

  -- REST OF LOGIC

  $aggr_alias = -- AGGR DATA;

 }
```

**Usage :**

```
aggr_data = AGGR_DATA(browser_data_alias,'country');
```

Pass the required field name to macro.